# do paypal classic api support ACH payments?

Tags: java, paypal

I already have integrated PayPal classic API in my web app for credit card payments. Now I need to provide support for ACH transactions. I have gone through PayPal documentations and all links for ACH leads me to PayPal Payflow pro API. So just want to confirm that for ACH payments we have to integrate Payflow pro api.